# Loop through results Simple XML php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am not sure how to loop through a Simple XML response. I just started exploring XML and can loop fine through PHP MYSQL but not through Simple XML. Any help?

```
$XML = "&xml=<HotelListRequest><city>$citysearch</city><currencyCode>£</currencyCode><arrivalDate>01/17/2016</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/18/2016</departureDate><supplierType>E</supplierType><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>$noaddults</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>$nochildren</numberOfChildren></Room></RoomGroup><numberOfResults>5</numberOfResults><locale>en_US</locale><sort>PRICE</sort></HotelListRequest>";

// Sending Request to API

$header[] = "Accept: application/xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$XML);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$XML );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

The Output is

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [customerSessionId] => xxxxxxxx-6DB54xxxx [numberOfRoomsRequested] => 1 [moreResultsAvailable] => true [cacheKey] => 41ab978e:151c66db542:-446a [cacheLocation] => 10.186.170.129:7300 [HotelList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 5 [activePropertyCount] => 1253 ) [HotelSummary] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [order] => 0 ) [hotelId] => 402789 [name] => Venture Hostel [address1] => 86 Tanner's Hill [city] => London [postalCode] => SE8 4PN [countryCode] => GB [airportCode] => LHR [supplierType] => E [propertyCategory] => 5 [hotelRating] => 2.0 [confidenceRating] => 52 [amenityMask] => 133120 [tripAdvisorRating] => 3.0 [locationDescription] => In London (Lewisham) [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Venture Hostel in London (Lewisham), you'll be close to Greenwich Market and O2 Arena. This hostel is within close proximity of Cutty Sark and [highRate] => 8.36 [lowRate] => 8.36 [rateCurrencyCode] => GBP [latitude] => 51.47361 [longitude] => -0.02712 [proximityDistance] => 3.9014914 [proximityUnit] => MI [hotelInDestination] => true [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/5000000/4920000/4916900/4916812/4916812_41_t.jpg [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/55505/hotels/402789/overview?lang=en&currency=GBP&standardCheckin=1/17/2016&standardCheckout=1/18/2016&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2 [RoomRateDetailsList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RoomRateDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [roomTypeCode] => 200585535 [rateCode] => 205900877 [maxRoomOccupancy] => 2 [quotedRoomOccupancy] => 1 [minGuestAge] => 0 [roomDescription] => Shared Dormitory, Mixed Dorm (8 Bed) [currentAllotment] => 12 [propertyAvailable] => true [propertyRestricted] => false [expediaPropertyId] => 4916812 [rateKey] => 9b7dbc12-65ba-4a72-b9c0-f991e610f9ee [RateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [priceBreakdown] => true [promo] => false [rateChange] => false ) [ChargeableRateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [averageBaseRate] => 8.36 [averageRate] => 8.36 [commissionableUsdTotal] => 12.45 [currencyCode] => GBP [maxNightlyRate] => 8.36 [nightlyRateTotal] => 8.36 [surchargeTotal] => 11.70 [total] => 20.06 ) [NightlyRatesPerRoom] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baseRate] => 8.36 [rate] => 8.36 [promo] => false ) ) ) [Surcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 2 ) [Surcharge] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => ExtraPersonFee [amount] => 8.36 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => TaxAndServiceFee [amount] => 3.34 ) ) ) ) ) ) [ValueAdds] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 2 ) [ValueAdd] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2048 ) [description] => Free Wireless Internet ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) [description] => Continental Breakfast ) ) ) ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [order] => 1 ) [hotelId] => 325381 [name] => Hostel 639 [address1] => 639 Harrow Road [address2] => Kensal Green [city] => London [postalCode] => NW10 5NU [countryCode] => GB [airportCode] => LCY [supplierType] => E [propertyCategory] => 5 [hotelRating] => 2.0 [confidenceRating] => 52 [amenityMask] => 256 [tripAdvisorRating] => 2.0 [locationDescription] => In London (North London) [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Hostel 639 in London (North London), you'll be close to Portobello Road Market and Royal Albert Hall. This hostel is close to Imperial College London [highRate] => 9.77 [lowRate] => 8.47 [rateCurrencyCode] => GBP [latitude] => 51.53012 [longitude] => -0.22551 [proximityDistance] => 5.5449877 [proximityUnit] => MI [hotelInDestination] => true [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/3000000/2840000/2831600/2831521/2831521_73_t.jpg [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/55505/hotels/325381/overview?lang=en&currency=GBP&standardCheckin=1/17/2016&standardCheckout=1/18/2016&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2 [RoomRateDetailsList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RoomRateDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [roomTypeCode] => 200052408 [rateCode] => 200307052 [maxRoomOccupancy] => 8 [quotedRoomOccupancy] => 0 [minGuestAge] => 18 [roomDescription] => Shared Dormitory, Mixed Dorm (8 Beds) [promoId] => 214239009 [promoDescription] => Save 13% [currentAllotment] => 75 [propertyAvailable] => true [propertyRestricted] => false [expediaPropertyId] => 2831521 [rateKey] => 57c8780b-2a50-45ff-8f0a-bb08622f071e [RateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [priceBreakdown] => true [promo] => true [rateChange] => false ) [ChargeableRateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [averageBaseRate] => 9.77 [averageRate] => 8.47 [commissionableUsdTotal] => 12.62 [currencyCode] => GBP [maxNightlyRate] => 8.47 [nightlyRateTotal] => 8.47 [surchargeTotal] => 11.86 [total] => 20.33 ) [NightlyRatesPerRoom] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baseRate] => 9.77 [rate] => 8.47 [promo] => true ) ) ) [Surcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 2 ) [Surcharge] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => ExtraPersonFee [amount] => 8.47 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => TaxAndServiceFee [amount] => 3.39 ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [order] => 2 ) [hotelId] => 423378 [name] => RestUp London - Hostel [address1] => 172 New Kent Road [city] => London [postalCode] => SE1 4YT [countryCode] => GB [airportCode] => LTN [supplierType] => E [propertyCategory] => 5 [hotelRating] => 2.0 [confidenceRating] => 52 [amenityMask] => 196864 [tripAdvisorRating] => 3.0 [locationDescription] => In London (South Bank) [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at RestUp London - Hostel, you'll be centrally located in London, convenient to London South Bank University and London Bridge. This hostel is close to [highRate] => 11.22 [lowRate] => 8.49 [rateCurrencyCode] => GBP [latitude] => 51.49413 [longitude] => -0.0906 [proximityDistance] => 1.0447516 [proximityUnit] => MI [hotelInDestination] => true [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/6000000/5570000/5568700/5568679/5568679_65_t.jpg [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/55505/hotels/423378/overview?lang=en&currency=GBP&standardCheckin=1/17/2016&standardCheckout=1/18/2016&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2 [RoomRateDetailsList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RoomRateDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [roomTypeCode] => 200352902 [rateCode] => 202156304 [maxRoomOccupancy] => 10 [quotedRoomOccupancy] => 1 [minGuestAge] => 18 [roomDescription] => Bed in 10-Bed Dormitory with Shared Bathroom [promoId] => 213611478 [promoDescription] => Save 24% [currentAllotment] => 21 [propertyAvailable] => true [propertyRestricted] => false [expediaPropertyId] => 5568679 [rateKey] => cf24b9fd-4e06-4086-b142-236832744d6b [RateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [priceBreakdown] => true [promo] => true [rateChange] => false ) [ChargeableRateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [averageBaseRate] => 11.22 [averageRate] => 8.49 [commissionableUsdTotal] => 12.65 [currencyCode] => GBP [maxNightlyRate] => 8.49 [nightlyRateTotal] => 8.49 [surchargeTotal] => 11.88 [total] => 20.37 ) [NightlyRatesPerRoom] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baseRate] => 11.22 [rate] => 8.49 [promo] => true ) ) ) [Surcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 2 ) [Surcharge] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => ExtraPersonFee [amount] => 8.49 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => TaxAndServiceFee [amount] => 3.39 ) ) ) ) ) ) [ValueAdds] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [ValueAdd] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2048 ) [description] => Free Wireless Internet ) ) ) ) ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [order] => 3 ) [hotelId] => 394808 [name] => The Londonears Hostel [address1] => 1 Barkston Gardens [city] => London [postalCode] => SW5 0ER [countryCode] => GB [airportCode] => LHR [supplierType] => E [propertyCategory] => 5 [hotelRating] => 2.0 [confidenceRating] => 52 [amenityMask] => 0 [tripAdvisorRating] => 2.0 [locationDescription] => Near London Natural History Museum [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at The Londonears Hostel, you'll be centrally located in London, convenient to Kensington Roof Gardens and Imperial College London. This hostel is close [highRate] => 10.45 [lowRate] => 10.45 [rateCurrencyCode] => GBP [latitude] => 51.49285 [longitude] => -0.18991 [proximityDistance] => 3.2764168 [proximityUnit] => MI [hotelInDestination] => true [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/5000000/4700000/4694100/4694093/4694093_70_t.jpg [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/55505/hotels/394808/overview?lang=en&currency=GBP&standardCheckin=1/17/2016&standardCheckout=1/18/2016&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2 [RoomRateDetailsList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RoomRateDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [roomTypeCode] => 200134869 [rateCode] => 200753387 [maxRoomOccupancy] => 10 [quotedRoomOccupancy] => 1 [minGuestAge] => 0 [roomDescription] => Shared Dormitory, 1 Single Bed (10 Bed) [currentAllotment] => 13 [propertyAvailable] => true [propertyRestricted] => false [expediaPropertyId] => 4694093 [rateKey] => fd7fe5b5-f791-4375-857b-f418c7e39896 [RateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [priceBreakdown] => true [promo] => false [rateChange] => false ) [ChargeableRateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [averageBaseRate] => 8.71 [averageRate] => 8.71 [commissionableUsdTotal] => 15.57 [currencyCode] => GBP [maxNightlyRate] => 8.71 [nightlyRateTotal] => 8.71 [surchargeTotal] => 12.19 [total] => 20.90 ) [NightlyRatesPerRoom] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baseRate] => 8.71 [rate] => 8.71 [promo] => false ) ) ) [Surcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 2 ) [Surcharge] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => ExtraPersonFee [amount] => 10.45 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => TaxAndServiceFee [amount] => 1.74 ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [order] => 4 ) [hotelId] => 336155 [name] => Palmers Lodge Swiss Cottage - Hostel [address1] => 40 College Crescent [address2] => Swiss Cottage [city] => London [postalCode] => NW3 5LB [countryCode] => GB [airportCode] => LHR [supplierType] => E [propertyCategory] => 5 [hotelRating] => 2.0 [confidenceRating] => 52 [amenityMask] => 264 [tripAdvisorRating] => 4.0 [locationDescription] => In London (Hampstead) [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Palmers Lodge Swiss Cottage - Hostel in London (Hampstead), you'll be minutes from Swiss Cottage Farmers' Market and Hampstead Theatre. This hostel [highRate] => 30.0 [lowRate] => 24.0 [rateCurrencyCode] => GBP [latitude] => 51.54552 [longitude] => -0.1756 [proximityDistance] => 4.6696467 [proximityUnit] => MI [hotelInDestination] => true [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/4000000/3130000/3125600/3125521/3125521_83_t.jpg [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/55505/hotels/336155/overview?lang=en&currency=GBP&standardCheckin=1/17/2016&standardCheckout=1/18/2016&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2 [RoomRateDetailsList] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RoomRateDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [roomTypeCode] => 200145115 [rateCode] => 200813400 [maxRoomOccupancy] => 2 [quotedRoomOccupancy] => 2 [minGuestAge] => 0 [roomDescription] => Mixed Dorm (9 Double Bed) [promoId] => 213544183 [promoDescription] => Save 20% [currentAllotment] => 6 [propertyAvailable] => true [propertyRestricted] => false [expediaPropertyId] => 3125521 [rateKey] => 1ce0444e-0fc9-47c8-87b7-8641b184b173 [RateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [priceBreakdown] => true [promo] => true [rateChange] => false ) [ChargeableRateInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [averageBaseRate] => 26.00 [averageRate] => 20.00 [commissionableUsdTotal] => 35.75 [currencyCode] => GBP [maxNightlyRate] => 20.00 [nightlyRateTotal] => 20.00 [surchargeTotal] => 4.00 [total] => 24.00 ) [NightlyRatesPerRoom] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baseRate] => 26.00 [rate] => 20.00 [promo] => true ) ) ) [Surcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [Surcharge] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => TaxAndServiceFee [amount] => 4.00 ) ) ) ) ) [ValueAdds] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 1 ) [ValueAdd] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2048 ) [description] => Free Wireless Internet ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

later on i just use simple ECHO statements which output the xml data, however, it only shows for one hotel and not for the rest of the available hotels.

Thnx for your help.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `print_r($response);` (put the statement right after the call to `simplexml_load_string()`).

Comment: done @Jan hope this helps.

Comment: Just use `$response->customerSessionId` to get 'xxxxxxxx-6DB54xxxx', it works like an array.

Comment: Where do I use this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment: you can loop over SimpleXML objects just like in an array:

```
$XML = "&xml=<HotelListRequest><city>$citysearch</city><currencyCode>£</currencyCode><arrivalDate>01/17/2016</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/18/2016</departureDate><supplierType>E</supplierType><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>$noaddults</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>$nochildren</numberOfChildren></Room></RoomGroup><numberOfResults>5</numberOfResults><locale>en_US</locale><sort>PRICE</sort></HotelListRequest>";

// Sending Request to API

$header[] = "Accept: application/xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$XML);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$XML );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);

// to get the  customerSessionId xxxxxxxx-6DB54xxxx
echo "sessionID: " . $response->customerSessionId;

// to get the HotelList
print_r($response->HotelList);

// loop over the HotelList:
foreach ($response->HotelList as $hotel) {
    // do sth. useful with the hotel
    // e.g. build a pool or whatever ;-)
}
```